# Rational points on $y^2 = x + \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Does the title curve have any rational points when $x$ is not an integer when $y\neq \pm 1$ ?

My attempt: I considered congruences $\mod 4$ but it seems not to be yielding anything ?

Comment: what do you mean different denominators? a rational number can have various denominators.

Comment: $x = 2$, $y = \pm3/2$ comes to mind. And $x=0$, $y=\pm1/2$ of course. I am not sure whether that fulfills your criteria though.

Comment: @GDumphart, thank you very much for your observation. That brings us to the original question that i had: is $x$ always an integer ? I seem not to find any explanation for it.

Comment: Surely if you take $y$ to be a rational number, then $x=y^2-\frac{1}{4}$ is rational as well.

Comment: @πr8 yeah, so most rational points on that curve do not have $x$ as an integer.

Comment: Take $y = 1, x = \frac 34$ for example

Comment: @Mathmo123, sorry had forgotten to add the restriction that $y\neq \pm 1$

Comment: Take $y=2,x=\frac{15}4$ for example

Comment: Thank you all, now i'm convinced !

Comment: Or $(x,y) = (-\frac{1365}{5476}, \frac1{37})$.

Comment: (x,y) = (39/100, 4,5); 16/25 = 64/100 = 39/100 + 25/100 = 39/100 + 1/4.  (x, y) = (4/9, 5,6); 25/36 = 4/9 + 1/4 = (16 + 9)/36.  x's denominator must be a perfect square.  And 4(num) + (root(den))^2 must be a perfect square.  Many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = m/n; x = p/q$

$(m/n)^2 = p/q + 1/4 = (4p + q)/4q$

If $gcd(4p + q, 4q) = 1$ then $m/n = \pm \sqrt{4p + q}/2\sqrt{q}$ so $q$ is a perfect square and $4p + q$ is a perfect square.  There should be many possible solutions.  $x = 4/9; y=5/6$ for instance.

If $gcd(4p + q, 4q) \ne 1$ .. well, then q must be even as $gcd(p,q) = 1$ so p is odd.  If $q = 2q'; q'$ odd then $(m/n)^2 = (2p + q')/2q'$ which cant be rational as $2q'$ can't be a perfect square.  If $q = 4q'$ we have $(m/n)^2 = (p + q')/q'$ which is rational iff $q'$ and $p + q'$ are perfect squares which should have *MANY* solutions. Example: $q' = 25$ and $p = 29$ so $x = 29/100$ and $y = 4/5$.

====

$\pi r8$ in the comments:

$y^2 = x + 1/4 \iff x = y^2 - 1/4$.   D'oh!!!!!!!

$x = (y - 1/2)(y + 1/2) \implies $ gazillions of solutions.  And not, x or y being integers is *not* a requirement.

Still, my original requirement that $x$'s denominator be a perfect square is ....  Oh! DOUBLE D'OH!!!!!!

Why the *heck* didn't it occur to me to simply express $x$ in terms of $y$?  Why did I insist on expressing $y$ in terms of conditionals that it be the square root that $x$ be such that its denominator is square and its numerator is such that a difference between a square and the denominator.... oh, well.  Live and learn.

$y = m/n$ be any rational at all.  Then $x = (4m^2 - n^2)/4n^2$.  D'oh.  Always works....